# Azure SQL Database or SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: azure-sql-database, real-time, azure-synapse

I am working on a solution architecture and am having hard time choosing between Azure SQL DB or SQL DW.

The current scope involves around developing real-time BI reporting solution which is based on multiple sources. But in the long run the solution may be extended into a full fledged EDW and Marts.

I initially thought of using SQL DW so that for future scope the MPP capabilities could be used. But when I spoke to a mate who recently used SQL DW, he explained that the the development in SQL DW is not similar to SQL DB.

I have worked previously on Real Time reporting with no scope for EDW and we successfully used SQL DB. With this as well we can create Facts and Dimension and Marts.

Is there a strong case where I should be choosing SQL DW over SQL DB?

Comment: What sort of data volumes are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 4 TB limit of Azure SQL Database may be an important factor to consider when choosing between the two options. Queries can be faster with Azure SQL Data Warehouse since is a MPP solution. You can pause Azure SQL DW to save costs with Azure SQL Database you can scale down to Basic tier (when possible).

Azure SQL DB can support up to 6,400 concurrent queries and 32k active connections, where Azure SQL DW can only support up to 32 concurrent queries and 1,024 active connections.  So SQL DB is a much better solution if you are using something like a dashboard with thousands of users.

About developing for them, Azure SQL Database supports Entity Framework but Azure SQL DW does not support it.

I want also to give you a quick glimpse of how both of them compare in terms of performance 1 DWU is approximately 7.5 DTU (Database Throughput Unit, used to express the horse power of an OLTP Azure SQL Database) in capacity although they are not exactly comparable. More information about this comparison [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/maheshkshirsagar/2016/08/20/mpp-dwu-and-polybase-in-azure-sql-data-warehouse/).

Comment: SQL DW has supported 128 concurrent query executions for a few months now while concurrent sessions is still maxed at 1024. I would consider workload patterns as the most important consideration in deciding between SQL DB and SQL DW, particularly on how much compute you need per query and in aggregate on a regular business minute. Finally, I would avoid referencing the blog in your link in the future; the content isn't something I would point users to if they want to learn about SQL DW.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Despite the thread has been marked as answered I would love to see you answering the thread to make more visible your consideration about workload patterns. I learned something new with that. Would you consider valuable the comparison between DWU and DTU contained on the article?

Comment: No, I won't compare DWU and DTU. While there appears to be some mathematical relation between them, the way resources are provisioned, governed and consumed are quite different. Assuming you get the same or even similar performance or compute capacity by matching the ratios will lead you pretty far wrong. That aside, the blog is wrong about memory per node and Polybase. It's also misleading about concurrency and DWU.

Comment: @SQLmojoe Thank you for all that information and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I think the two most important data points you can have here is the volume of data you're processing and the number of concurrent queries that you need to support. When talking about processing large volume data, and by large, I mean more than 3tb (which is not even really large, but large enough), then Azure SQL Data Warehouse becomes a juggernaut. The parallel processing is simply amazing (it's amazing at smaller volumes too, but you're paying a lot of money for overkill). However, the one issue can be the simultaneous query limit. It currently has a limit of 128 concurrent queries with a limit of 1,000 queries queued ([read more here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-service-capacity-limits)). If you're using the Data Warehouse as a data warehouse to process large amounts of data and then feed them into data marts where the majority of the querying takes place, this isn't a big deal. If you're planning to open this to large volume querying, it quickly becomes problematic.

Answer those two questions, query volume and data volume, and you can more easily decide between the two.

Additional factors can include the issues around the T-SQL currently supported. It is less than traditional SQL Server. Again, for most purposes around data warehousing, this is not an issue. For a full blown reporting server, it might be.

Most people successfully implementing Azure SQL Data Warehouse are using a combination of the warehouse for processing and storage and Azure SQL Database for data marts. There are exceptions when dealing with very large data volumes that need the parallel processing, but don't require lots of queries.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you responses Grant and Alberto. The responses have cleared a lot of air to make a choice.

Since, the data would be subject to dash-boarding and querying, I am tilting towards SQL Database instead of SQL DW.

Thanks again.